# Google Cloud Messaging - server connection

Tags: java, android, smack, google-cloud-messaging

I started to write some application using Google Cloud Messaging, but I have problem with the server. I used code from Android Developer side - Java sample using the Smack library (I will not upload code here, because it is quite long):

[GCM Cloud connection Server (XMPP)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html)

I have turn on Google Cloud Messaging on Google Apis and I changed my SENDER_ID, API KEY and Registration_ID, but when I start the program I have errors like this:

```
    gcm.googleapis.com:5235 Exception: XMPPError connecting to gcm.googleapis.com:5235.; : remote-server-error(502)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:604)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1026)
        at SmackCcsClient.connect(SmackCcsClient.java:248)
        at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:342)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:495)
        at SmackCcsClient.send(SmackCcsClient.java:132)
        at SmackCcsClient.main(SmackCcsClient.java:357)

SmackCcsClient.java:248 -> `connection.connect();`

SmackCcsClient.java:342 -> `ccsClient.connect(userName, password);`

SmackCcsClient.java:132 -> `connection.sendPacket(request);`

SmackCcsClient.java:357 -> `ccsClient.send(createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload, collapseKey,timeToLive, delayWhileIdle));`
```

Maybe you know what I done wrong?

Comment: can you post the relevant code with which you try to connect.

Comment: I used code from link - under Java sample using the Smack library title

Comment: @CookieMonssster: how did you solved your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by looking for some firewall rules.

Maybe you can try to add a rule to grant access from inside to gcm.googleapis.com.

PS: Maybe you'll have to specify an IP instead of gcm.googleapis.com